# The file I converted with FFMPEG in Firebase Cloud function is not accessable

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

The following is my cloud function code.

```
    exports.increaseVolume = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
    const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.

    // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an audio.
    if (!contentType.startsWith('video/mp4')) {
      console.log('This is not an audio.');
      return null;
    }

    // Get the file name.
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
    // Exit if the audio is already converted.
    if (fileName.endsWith('_output.mp4')) {
      console.log('Already a converted audio.');
      return null;
    }

    // Download file from bucket.
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
    // We add a '_output.flac' suffix to target audio file name. That's where we'll upload the converted audio.
    const targetTempFileName = fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '') + '_output.mp4';
    const targetTempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), targetTempFileName);
    const targetStorageFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), targetTempFileName);

    await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath});
    console.log('Audio downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
    // Convert the audio to mono channel using FFMPEG.

    let command = ffmpeg(tempFilePath)
        .audioFilters([
        {
          filter: 'volume',
          options: '5dB'
        },
        {
          filter: 'afftdn'
        }
      ])
        .format('mp4')
        .output(targetTempFilePath);

    await promisifyCommand(command);
    console.log('Output audio created at', targetTempFilePath);
    // Uploading the audio.
    await bucket.upload(targetTempFilePath, {destination: targetStorageFilePath});

    console.log('Output audio uploaded to', targetStorageFilePath);

    // Once the audio has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
    fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
    fs.unlinkSync(targetTempFilePath);

    return console.log('Temporary files removed.', targetTempFilePath);
  });
```

This is how the file in my storage bucket shows. Where do I get the download link or how can I access the file?. When I typed the link in the browser it returns a JSON saying 403 - unauthorized access.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) method as follows:

```
const uploadResp = await bucket.upload(targetTempFilePath, {destination: targetStorageFilePath});

const file = uploadResp[0];

const options = {
       action: 'read',
       expires: '03-17-2025'
};

const getSignedUrlResponse = await file.getSignedUrl(options);
const url = getSignedUrlResponse[0];

//Do wathever you want with this url: save it in Firestore for example
```

Answer (score 0):

The message you are facing is about permissions. Who should have access to what?

First of all you have to think about your business logic. Who should have access to that file? Is it good if that file should be public? Is there a time-frame in which the file should be accessible? The data should remain in the Bucket or it can be deleted?

I think there are two options for you:

1. Create a Bucket with [public data](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public), in such case the data would accessible for everyone who has access to the specific filename in the Bucket.
2. If the above is not allowed, then you can create a [SignedURL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), as mentioned by @Renaud Tarnec [link example](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl-examples). You should keep in mind that the SignedURL has time-limited access and everyone who has the URL of it, will be able to get the object. Once the time is expired, the object will not be longer accessible.

Once you have defined this, you can either [delete the object in your Bucket programatically](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#storage-delete-object-nodejs) or you can set a [Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle). There, you can set configurations which contains a set of rules, for example, delete objects created by their age (in days).